# Extract the address of a search criteria in a list combining Cell/Index

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below Excel sheet:

```
        A             B            C            D            E         F
1     CW10          CW14         $A$5
2     CW11
3     CW12
4     CW13
5     CW14
6     CW15
7
```

In `Column A` I have a list of calender weeks. 
In `Cell B1` I enter a certain calender week and in `Cell D1` I get the corresponding address of this calender week in `Column A`. 
For this functionality in `Cell C1` I use the formula: `=CELL("address",INDEX(A1:A7,MATCH(B1,A1:A7,0),0))`

---

Now, I want use the exact same formula in `VBA`. Therefore, I first created the `INDEX` part of it:

```
WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheet1.Range("A1:A7").Value, WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheet1.Range("B1").Value, Sheet1.Range("A1:A7").Value, 0), 0)
```

This part already worsk perfectly.

---

Then I tried to add `CELL("address")` to it:

```
WorksheetFunction.Cell("address", WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheet1.Range("A1:A7").Value, WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheet1.Range("B1").Value, Sheet1.Range("A1:A7").Value, 0), 0))
.Value)
```

However, for this I get `runtime error 424`.

What do I need to change in my formula to make it work or is there any other alternative to extract the address of a search criteria in a range?

Comment: Use `Range.Find` or `Application.Match`. There is no `WorksheetFunction.Cell` method.

Comment: If you need the address: `WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheet1.Range("B1").Value, Sheet1.Range("A1:A7").Value, 0), 0)` gives you the row number, so just tack on the column letter `A` in front of it.

Comment: The `Cell` function is not needed in VBA, because you work with the object model instead. A `Range` object has all the metadata you can dream of, including an `Address`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With reference to the comments there are two solutions for this issue:

---

**Option 1: Range.Find**

```
Sub Option_01()
Range_01 = Sheet1.Range("A1:A7").Find(WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheet1.Range("A1:A7").Value, WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheet1.Range("B1").Value, Sheet1.Range("A1:A7").Value, 0), 0)).Address
Sheet1.Range("C1").Value = Range_01
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, by testing this solution with more complex data I got some issues.

---

**Option 2: Application.Match**

```
Sub Option_02()
Row = Application.Match(Sheet1.Range("B1").Value, Sheet1.Range("A1:A7"), 0) + Sheet1.Range("A1:A7").Row - 1
Range_01 = ("$" & Split(Sheet1.Range("A1:A7").Address, "$")(1)) & "$"
Sheet1.Range("C1").Value = Range_01 & Row
End Sub
```